# Threads not getting stored in sequence in set

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, hashset, reentrantlock

I'm trying to add 10 threads to a set and name them sequentially. But when I debug to see the set,  threads are not stored in sequential order. Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
 Set<Thread> allThreads = new HashSet<Thread>();
        final DemoClass demo = new DemoClass();
    

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        demo.getName();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        System.out.println("We have a problem");
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.setName("Thread_" + (i + 1));
            allThreads.add(thread);
        }

        for (Thread t : allThreads) {
            t.start();
        }

        for (Thread t : allThreads) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
```

When I see allThreads, the threads are jumbled everytime .

Comment: Sets have no requirement to store threads in any specific order. Use a list if you want threads to be in the order you added them.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use a `HashSet` here, you are guaranteed to have no duplicates anyway, so you just add extra overhead

Comment: On top of PiRocks said, if you actually have to use a Set, pick one that is ordered, like `TreeSet` (anything implementing `SortedSet`)

Comment: TreeSet will be ordered by the elements' natural order, as I understand the question, the order should be the insertation order, not natural order.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of HashSet

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
> (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
> iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
> the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null
> element.

If you want to keep elements on insertation order, you can use for example `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

Hashset does not maintain order, As mentioned by zlaval - you can use LinkedList or ArrayList.

But if you want to avoid duplicates and also maintain the insertion order, you can use

**LinkedHashSet**

From docs:

Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

Comment: Thank you to mantioned, it can be life saving some time. Also, if there is no dupe or it does not matter, using arraylist is better coz it has a better performance.